# Puppet: Could not reserve enough space for object heap. Could not create the Java virtual machine

Tags: java, puppet

I've the following two errors on my puppetmaster when i try to run the manifests on the masternode:

```
change from absent to latest failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/keytool -importcert 
-noprompt -alias puppetca -file /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem 
-keystore /etc/puppetlabs/activemq/broker.ts -trustcacerts' returned 1: 
Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 
object heap Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

and...

```
change from absent to latest failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/keytool 
-importkeystore -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore 
 /etc/puppetlabs/activemq/broker.ks -srckeystore 
 /tmp/domain.com.20130221-957-17scina-0 -alias domain.com' returned 1: 
 Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space 
 for object heap Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

(i've changed my domain to domain.com)

I tried to set the activemq_heap_mb parameter, but it doesn't help.

I appreciate any suggestions :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a -Xmx128m to your keytool command.

If you are still getting the error try -Xmx256m or -Xmx512m

Comment: Looks like he does not have enough memory for JVM, so a smaller heap might work, not bigger.

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks.